# Elasticsearch, Tire, and Nested queries/associations with mongoid

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm using ElasticSearch with Tire to index and search a mongoid model, and I've been searching for the "right" way to index and search an embedded associations. I have a fully functional set up for this model but for some reason i can search for everything except by a field in a embedded model (ResourceTag)

### Unnecessary code removed

```
class Resource
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :tags, :class_name => "ResourceTag"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => true

  # Tire
  mapping do
    indexes :_id
    indexes :version,             analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    indexes :created_at,          type: 'date', index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :updated_at,          type: 'date', index: :not_analyzed    
    indexes :assignment do
      indexes :_id
      indexes :name,                analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
      indexes :current_state,                analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    do
    indexes :resource_files do
      indexes :_id
      indexes :name,                analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    end
    indexes :tags do
      indexes :_id
      indexes :name,                analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    self.to_json(
      :include => {
        :assignment => {
          :methods => :formatted_current_state
        }, 
        :resource_files => {
          :methods => [:is_video, :is_image]
        },
        :tags => nil
      }
    )
  end
end

class ResourceTag
  include Mongoid::Document

  # Attributes
  attr_accessible :name

  # Fields
  field :name, :type => String

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false

  # Relations
  embedded_in :resource

 end
```

i'm not really sure what is wrong with my code but i'm sure i got it working before and now it screwed up :s

i was looking for an example of tire with mongoid and embedded documents but no luck and i'm runnign out of ideas.

Thanks for any ideas and contributions.